# XML error when build symfony project

Tags: xml, symfony

When build symfony2 project. Show view problem flowing.

Description: Referenced file contains errors (http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..." 
Resource: Doctrine.Tests.Models.DDC117.DDC117Translation.dcm.xml 
Path: /MySymfony/vendor/doctrine/tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Mapping/xml
Location: line 1
Type: XML Problem

I think the link(http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd) in the xml file die.
Help me out this error eclipse config.